# Objects go out of scope when added to STL container

Tags: c++, stl

I'm currently adding objects to a container (Vector), but as soon as the method ends the vector is empty again.  How is this possible?

```
int getNumber(std::string input, int& index) {
    int i = 0;
    bool hasNegative = false;
    while (true) {
        char c = input[index + i];
        if (c == '-') {
            if (hasNegative) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                hasNegative = true;
            }
        }
        else if (!isdigit(c)) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    int result = atoi(input.substr(index, i).c_str());
    index += i;
    return result;
}

Expression makeExpression(std::string input, int& index) {
    Function func = getOperator(input[index]);
    Function func1 = getOperator(input[index + 1]);
    if (input[index + 2] != '=') {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
    index += 3;
    int equals = getNumber(input, index);

    std::vector<Function> op{ func, func1 };
    return Expression(op, equals);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string input = std::string(argv[argc - 1]);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;

    int index = 0;

    std::vector<Expression> expressions;
    expressions.reserve(6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Expression e = makeExpression(input, index);
        expressions.push_back(e);
        e.evaluate();
        Expression::ResultSet results = e.getAnswers(); // Empty!
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        for (std::tuple<int, int, int> answer : results) {
            std::cout << std::get<0>(answer) << " " << std::get<1>(answer) << " " << std::get<2>(answer) << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Expression

```
class Expression {
public:
    typedef std::function<int(int, int)> Function;
    typedef std::vector<Function> OperatorSet;
    OperatorSet opSet;

    typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> Result;
    typedef std::vector<Result> ResultSet;
    ResultSet resultSet;

    int equals;

    Expression(OperatorSet opSet, int equals) : resultSet(), opSet(opSet), equals(equals) {
    }

    ResultSet getAnswers()const {
        return resultSet;
    }

    void evaluate() {
        Function one = opSet[0];
        Function two = opSet[1];
        // Both + or -
        if (isBasicArithmetic(one) && isBasicArithmetic(two)) {
            FactorSet set = getSumsOfNine(equals, false);
            for (IntPair pair : set) {
                FactorSet set1 = getSumsOfNine(pair.second, true);
                for (IntPair pair1 : set1) {
                    if (pair.first == pair1.first || pair.first == pair1.second) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    resultSet.push_back(Result(pair.first, pair1.first, pair1.second));
                }
            }
        }
        // One
        else if (isBasicArithmetic(one)) {
            FactorSet set = getSumsOfNine(equals, false);
            for (IntPair pair : set) {

                FactorSet set1 = getFactorsOfNine(pair.second, true);

                for (IntPair pair1 : set1) {
                    if (pair.first == pair1.first || pair.first == pair1.second) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    resultSet.push_back(Result(pair.first, pair1.first, pair1.second));
                }
            }
        }
        // Two
        else if (isBasicArithmetic(two)) {
            FactorSet set = getSumsOfNine(equals, false);
            for (IntPair pair : set) {

                FactorSet set1 = getFactorsOfNine(pair.second, true);

                for (IntPair pair1 : set1) {
                    if (pair.first == pair1.first || pair.first == pair1.second) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    resultSet.push_back(Result(pair1.first, pair1.second, pair.first));
                }
            }
        }
        // Both
        else {
            FactorSet set = getFactorsOfNine(equals, false);
            for (IntPair pair : set) {
                if (pair.second > 9 + 8) {
                    continue;
                }

                FactorSet set1 = getFactorsOfNine(pair.second, true);

                for (IntPair pair1 : set1) {
                    if (pair.first == pair1.first || pair.first == pair1.second) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    resultSet.push_back(Result(pair1.first, pair1.second, pair.first));
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << resultSet.size() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And at the end of the method body resultSet has the correct size, but by the next method call resultSet is zero again.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you've posted so far (though I notice that your `getAnswers()` returns a *copy* of the result set rather than a reference), but I still don't see the code that's actually calling `evaluate()` followed by `getAnswers()`.

Comment: ...and you're absolutely certain you're effectively invoking push_backs into resultSet?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes @carlosdc. Unless something in the above code is wrong.

Comment: Done @Wyzard.  I can confirm the input is parsed correctly and the Expression object is created correctly, but I posted that code just in case.

Comment: Another suggest, you can try to simulate these codes in a new test project. By simpler and simpler, the actual answer will been revealed.

Comment: I still don't see a problem that'd cause the behavior you say is happening, but I can't attempt to reproduce the problem locally since the code here isn't self-contained.  See if you can reduce the problem to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), and if you don't figure out the cause in the process of doing that, ask a new question with the SSCCE.

Comment: @Tips48: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you statically create objects and then add their references to a vector or any container in a method, when you leave the method they will be popped off the stack and won't exit. This could be causing your problem, if it is, instead dynamically allocate the objects you add to your vector with new or malloc.

Comment: As show as his code, he statically create the vector as member, not in a method.

Comment: Did he dynamically create the objects he adds to the vector in the methods?

Answer (score 0):

In your main(), you have a loop. In each iteration, you create a new **Expression** object, which initializes its **resultSet** member to be an empty vector.

If you want **resultSet** to accumulate data although **evaluate()** is called upon a different object every time, you can make resultSet a static member of **Expression**.

Another option will be declaring a vector in **main()**, and appending the result of **getAnswers()** into it on every call.